# Find and replace a word in DOC document Perl

Tags: perl

I have bunch of Microsoft Word documents, and want to find and replace a word, e.g.

find the word **banana** replace it with **apple**

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3774799/133939)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm).

It seems that your interaction would look about like this (completely untested):

```
use Win32::OLE;

my $word = Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application') or die "Could not find Word.\n";

my $doc = $word->Documents->Open($filename);
my $content = valof $doc->{Content};
$content =~ s/banana/apple/g;
$doc->{Content} = $content;
$doc->Save();
$doc->Close();
$word->Quit();
```

Read the Win32::OLE documentation in conjunction with the VB documents for better/further information.

You might also find the tool "Multireplace" at the bottom of [this page](http://rath.ca/Misc/VBA/VBA_Word.html) interesting.

Comment: You can't regex-substitute on a Range object.

Comment: @Zaid: Thanks for the information.  I now edited to use `valof`, but I can't test this.  Perhaps you have a better answer?

Comment: There's a reasonable example in the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774799/how-do-i-apply-formatting-to-a-particular-word-in-a-docx-file-using-win32ole-in) I linked.

Comment: It's also possible to script Word's find-and-replace functionality through Win32::OLE. I've forgotten how it's actually exposed, as I last used this about 10 years ago, but it is possible.

Comment: @Svante:Getting Error Can't call method "valof" on an undefined value at word_find_replace.pl line 10.